# Attaching a Docker Container automatically to an IP Address/DNS

Tags: networking, dns, docker, ip, containers

I'm trying to make the Docker containers I start up automatically route/connect to the IP address given, essentially do this

```
    sudo docker run -it -name server -p 10.118.52.235:5672:5672 leemount96/firstserver
```

automatically, that is make the container connect to the IP address. I've read that there are ways to do something like this by modifying DOCKER_OPTS, but it was unclear on how to do that and what doing that actually did.

Thanks

Comment: You can explain in more details ?

Comment: Figured it out, had to edit the DOCKER_OPTS inside the /etc/default/docker file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that sometimes the DOCKER_OPTS are ignored (see [issues/9889](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9889))

In those instances, you would need

```
sudo docker -H tcp://10.118.52.235:5672 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -d
```